# Understanding how the loss was calculated for the SQuAD task in BERT paper

Tags: natural-language-processing, objective-functions, papers, bert

In the [BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf), section 4.2 covers the SQuAD training.

From my understanding, there are two extra parameters trained, they are two vectors with the same dimension as the hidden size, so the same dimensions as the contextualized embeddings in BERT. They are S (for start) and E (for End). For each, a softmax is taken with S and each of the final contextualized embeddings to get a score for the correct Start position. And the same thing is done for E and the correct end position.

I get up to this part. But I am having trouble figuring out how the did the labeling and final loss calculations, which is described in this paragraph

> and the maximum scoring span is used as the prediction. The training objective is the loglikelihood of the correct start and end positions.

What do they mean by "maximum scoring span is used as the prediction"?

Furthermore, how does that play into

> The training objective is the loglikelihood of the correct start and end positions

From this source: https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2017/08/13/softmax-and-the-negative-log-likelihood/

It says the log-likelihood is only applied to the correct classes. So, we are only calculating the softmax for the correct positions only, not any of the incorrect positions.

If this interpretation is correct, then the loss will be

```
Loss = -Log( Softmax(S*T(predictedStart) / Sum(S*Ti) ) -Log( Softmax(E*T(predictedEnd) / Sum(S*Ti) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These answers are based on my personal understanding of Bert from both the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) and [official_implementation](https://github.com/google-research/bert), hope it will help:

```
What do they mean by "maximum scoring span is used as the prediction"?
```

As you know in SQuAD the input sequence is divided to 2 parts: Question and Document (from which we extract the answer if possible).

Sometimes the input length exceeds the `max_seq_length` parameter, in this case the document is truncated to as many parts as needed and we end up having more than one input for the same question/document. Mention that the question is replicated in all the resulting inputs (see [line_350](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_squad.py) for details).

So in such cases, in order to determine the **predicted span** among all the generated-inputs we use the **maximum scoring** *i.e* `(max_start + max_end) / 2 = ( max(Softmax(S*Ti)) + max(Softmax(E*Ti)) ) / 2` of all the inputs related to the same question.

```
"The training objective is the loglikelihood of the correct start and end positions"
```

The loss is the average of the start_position loss `start_loss` and the end_postition loss `end_loss`. Each loss is computed in the same way: after applying the Softmax to the final output (i.e `S*Ti` or `E*Ti`) we use the real start/end postitions to compute the loss (see code below).

From [run_squad.py](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_squad.py) in Bert_repo:

```
 def compute_loss(logits, positions):
        one_hot_positions = tf.one_hot(positions, depth=seq_length, dtype=tf.float32)
        log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)
        loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_positions * log_probs, axis=-1))
        return loss

 start_positions = features["start_positions"]
 end_positions = features["end_positions"]

 start_loss = compute_loss(start_logits, start_positions)
 end_loss = compute_loss(end_logits, end_positions)

 total_loss = (start_loss + end_loss) / 2.0
```